# Ordering Items in a ListBox Using ComboBox

Tags: vb.net

(All of the names on the ListBox are actually .txt files, which contain different values that can be put into the program by a certain window.)

I'm trying to use a ComboBox to order items in a list by a certain value. So say I select "Sort by Alphabetical" in the ComboBox, I'd want it to sort the items in the ListBox in alphabetical order.

Also, if I were to have a certain value in the .txt files that I would like to sort by, is there a way I could order by that?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)? I hope you are not expecting us writing the code for you, do you? Because that's not gonna happen.

Comment: I'm not asking you to write code for me I'm just asking for some advice pertaining to how it should be written. I only know sorting by lists, but I don't know how to take the values from the .txt files and put them into a list. Are there any functions that would help? Not the whole code..

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far. Explain what difficulties you encountered so far with what you tried. Ask a real question. That's how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: I know how to add input onto ListBox objects. Currently, I am putting names of every text file from a directory into a ListBox. I need to change the order of the ListBox and I'm simply wondering if there are pre-defined functions that are available for me to use, or if I'm thinking way too hard, because the concept for sorting values by a certain condition cannot be too hard.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot sort the text files directly. You will have to create a class containing the information you are interesed in.

```
Public Class TextfileInfo
    Public Filename As String
    Public Filedate As DateTime
    Public Filesize As Integer
    Public SomeValueOfTextfile As String
    Public SomeOtherValueOfTextfile As String

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Filename
        ' Will be displayed in the ListBox.
    End Function
End Class
```

You can then change the listbox content like this

```
Dim files As New List(Of TextfileInfo)()
'TODO: add items to files

Dim displayList = From file In files _
      Order By file.Filesize _
      Select file
listBox1.Items.Clear()
listBox1.Items.AddRange(displayList.ToArray())
```

You can get the files and their info like this

```
Dim files As New List(Of TextfileInfo)()
Dim dir = New DirectoryInfo("C:\MyTextfiles")
Dim fileInfo As FileInfo() = dir.GetFiles("*.txt")
For Each fi As FileInfo In fileInfo
    Dim file = New TextfileInfo()
    file.Filesize = CInt(fi.Length)
    ' Add all other properties.
    ' Open the file and extract information from it.
    files.Add(file)
Next
```

I let you program the other details.